# Fixing simple Get-ADComputer : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Why did the below simple AD cmdlets fail? I'm trying to get all Windows Server OS that is online in my AD domain, into variable.

```
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter { Enabled -eq $True -and OperatingSystem -like "*Server*" } -Properties OperatingSystem -SearchBase "DC=DOMAIN,DC=com" | 
    Where-Object { Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet } | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

However, it is error:

```
Get-ADComputer : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.
+ $Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter { Enabled -eq $True -and OperatingS ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

How to make it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ADComputer` makes a *paged* query to Active Directory, and then starts outputting the results one-by-one.

If PowerShell takes too long between initially sending the query and then subsequently asking for the next page of the result set, the page cursor on the DC basically times out to free up resources and you get `invalid enumeration context`.

Instead of piping the output directly to  `Where-Object { Test-Connection ... }`, which in turn "backs up" the pipeline every time we're waiting for a ping to timeout, make the `Get-ADComputer` call in a nested pipeline (enclose it it `()`):

```
$Servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter { Enabled -eq $True -and OperatingSystem -like "*Server*" } -Properties OperatingSystem -SearchBase "DC=DOMAIN,DC=com") | 
    Where-Object { Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1 -Quiet } | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```